# Update an item on a list in my flutter app without having same item with updated value

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run the code, the list adds another item instead of updating the old item (still displaying the old item) which the index was found. I have also tried as using keys on my `listView.builder()` `listView.custom()`,  and on the Custom Widget I created which renders on the `listView.builder()` all give same result. Is there something I'm not doing right?

using the `indexWhere()` this way,

```
void updateProduct(String id, ProductSaver productSaver) {
    final prodIndex = _productList.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    final newProduct = ProductSaver(
        title: productSaver.title,
        description: productSaver.description,
        imageUrl: productSaver.imageUrl,
        price: productSaver.price);
    _productList[prodIndex] = newProduct as Product;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

and this way:

```
void updateProduct(String id, Product newItem){
final pIndex = _productList.indexWhere((element)=>element.id == id);
if(pIndex >= 0){
_productList[pIndex] = newItem;}
 notifyListeners();}
```

I also used the list`.contain()`

```
void updateProduct({String? id, required Product newItem}) {
        final itemIndex = _productList.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id! == id);
        if (_productList.contains(_productList[itemIndex])) {
          _productList[itemIndex] = newItem;
        }
        notifyListeners();
      }
```

Here is the `build()` of the code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final providerData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Products'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(EditProductScreen.routeName);
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 30,
            ),
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: MyColor.primaryColor,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 10),
          itemCount: providerData.item.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                UserProductItem(
                    id: providerData.item[index].id!,
                    imageUrl: providerData.item[index].imageUrl,
                    title: providerData.item[index].title),
            
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

the above  UserProductItem() Widget.

```
 class UserProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
      const UserProductItem({
        Key? key,
        required this.imageUrl,
        required this.title,
        required this.id,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      final String imageUrl;
      final String title;
      final String? id;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final productData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    
        return ListTile(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          leading: Image.network(
            imageUrl,
          ),
          title: Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: MyColor.primaryColor,
              fontSize: 17,
            ),
          ),
          trailing: FittedBox(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.edit,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context)
                        .pushNamed(EditProductScreen.routeName, arguments: id!);
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.delete_outline_outlined,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    productData.removeItem(id!);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your build method? I assume since you're using notifyListeners() you're using riverpod or some other sort of change notifier to handle the state? Setting something at an index definitely shouldn't grow your list. It must be something else listening to the list state or an issue in the build.

Comment: Ok , I'll add it to them original question

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it's because of the provider being in both the parent and the child. Do you need the provider in both? If the item in the ListView updates, maybe just pass the contents of the parent as parameters to the child and use a callback to remove items via a method in the parent.

Comment: I see that productData is only used to call a remove so maybe replace that with a callback and remove the provider from the UserProductItem

Comment: thank you for your answer. As you suggested, I have tried to use a callback , the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the value at a specific index. Instead you can try adding an item to the list

```dart
if (_productList.contains(_productList[itemIndex])) {
          _productList.add(newItem);//<--here
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't work.  I actually want to edit an already existing item not to add a new on.  The method i use to add new item works just fine.

Comment: are you trying to update the existing value or add a new one?

Comment: I want to update an existing item.